# how to add token with dynamic route in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I try to create an online shopping system for learning purposes in react.js. when the user clicks on a product the URL is

> /products/${id}

I want this id or name is not shown in the URL. but fetch the data of this id.

like

> localhost/products/{token or random something}

the main point of my question is clients don't show the product id or any info about the product in the URL. But the right product is shown according to the product id.

How can do this?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, simply avoid the use of React Router. Just render a component that shows product details.

E.g. you would have a component - `Products` that shows a list of products and a component that shows product details - `Product`:

```
const Products = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [isProductShown, showProduct] = useState(false);
  const [productId, setProductId] = useState();
  // fetch products in e.g. useEffect

  const handleProductClick = (id) => {
    showProduct(true);
    setProductId(id);
  }

  return isProductShown ? <Product id={productId}/> : ({products.map(product => <div key={product.id} onClick={() => handleProductClick(product.id)}>{product.name}</div>)})
}
```

P.S. Code might not be syntactically correct.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have a back end set up, you can create a "slug" property on your products so that you can route to them. Your objects would look something like this.

```
{
  id: 1
  name: "Sunglasses"
  price: 5.00
  slug: "sunglasses"
}
```

Then when you set up your routes, you can do so like this.

```
<Route exact path="/products/:slug" component={ProductPage} />
```

From there everything is the same as what you would do with an id. When you navigate to the page, grab the slug from the url and create a fetch function to go get the product based on the slug.